# Timer won't continue working after clicking some object(C# UNITY)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a lobby and here's what it looks like

[image]

Now this 5 object in the lobby has their own timer each object and it's properly working . so here's what I did.

**Table.cs**

```
public bool IsActive { get; private set; }

private float rTimer;

// Use this for initialization
void Start(){}

public IEnumerator Init()
{
    if (info_timer != null)
    {
        info_timer.text = timer = "[808080]0[-]";
    }
    yield return null;
}

public void ActivateTimer(bool activate = true)
{
    //if activate is true, then reset this timer to default.
    if (activate)
        rTimer = tzPlayInfo.Instance.gap;
        rTimer /= 1000.0f;

    IsActive = activate;
}

public void UpdateTimer(float deltaTime)
{
    //we can even check to see if the table is active or the timer has already timed out.
    if (!IsActive) return;

    rTimer -= deltaTime;

    if (rTimer <= 0.0f)
    {
        info_timer.text = timer = "[808080]0[-]";
        IsActive = false;
    }
    else
    {
        info_timer.text = rTimer.ToString("F0");
    }
}
```

Now on the **Main.cs** where in drives all the updates.

```
public class Main : MonoBehaviour
{
  const float gap = 20.0f;
  Table[] script_table;
  bool start_timer = false;
  int t_no;
  public static string Ctimer = "";

  public void Update()
  {
     for ( int i = 0; i < script_table.Length; i++ )
     script_table[i].UpdateTimer(Time.deltaTime);
   }

   // This method can now be used to Activate or De-Activate a timer.
   public void ActivateTimer ( int tableNumber, bool activate = true )
   {
      script_table[tableNumber ].ActivateTimer( activate );
   } 
 }
```

Now my problem is that when I click on of this table/object it will go inside and create another room like this

[image]

But the problem is that I couldn't get the data of timer of that object i clicked

for example if I click the first table and it has a timer of 15 seconds then i must obtain the 15 seconds data to display it on the room.

Comment: Can you show us the method which is called when you Click?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need to access the clicked object. you can find that object with its name or a specific tag.

**Find an object with the name :**

```
// This returns the GameObject named Hand.
    GameObject hand = GameObject.Find("Hand");
```

[GameObject.Find In Unity Manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.Find.html)

**Or you can set a tag on it in the inspector and find it by tag :**

```
GameObject respawn = GameObject.FindWithTag("Respawn");
```

[GameObject.FindWithTag In Unity Manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindWithTag.html)

**Then you can simply access to its attached script like this :**

```
gameObject.GetComponent<Table>();
```

Comment: I don't have any tags right there sir.

Comment: `Find` and `FindWithTag` will not be really useful if there are basically 5 identical objects in the scene.